# Car won't start hours after passing over water

Tags: electrical, vw, intermittent-problems, polo

Yesterday at night i was coming home and passed through some water (probably some broken pipe), and the car started to intermittently being on/off (electric part failure). It worked for about 1 kilometer until it completely died (luckily at my door).

I immediately recognized the problem, as in some hard rainy days it happened to me twice the car completely die. But it would be a matter of half an hour or something until it works again. Now has passed 15+ hours, and it's not turning on.

So, which connections should i check and blow to remove water? It's a 1998 VW Polo 1.0cc.

Comment: Is your air filter dry yet?

Comment: does it crank, or no power at all?  does headlights, radio, interior lights work?

Comment: I don't know about the air filter, but i assume it's dry, 20 hours passed. Yes it works everything, i turn the key it tries to turn on i keep the key on seconds but it just doesn't start. It's like without gasoline (but it have).

Comment: Sounds like a spark issue as if the ignition parts in your engine got wet and it's having trouble getting spark. If you have a manual look at the ignition system or like ignition control module or ignition coils and check those for moisture. Look up how to check each of those terminals one-by-one to see it you can determine if any are sparking or not... This may be a good starting point for you at least; you say electrical but it seems more like spark issues as in the high electrical charges that ignite the gas in the engine block when the air and fuel are mixed and compressed... BANG!!

Comment: @Tiago You're probably right that it's dry.by now but for future reference it takes just a couple seconds to check. Instructions for accessing the air filter can be found in your manual.

Comment: are there any codes in the computer? i'd suspect the crank position sensor first.

Comment: Did you get it running again? If did it would be great to know how you did it.